# Improve performance to render tiles from Geoserver on Google map

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, google-maps-api-3

I have started using GeoServer and PostgreSQL combination to render polygons (more than 4000) on Google Map. Everything seems to be fine.

However, when I zoom the map, layers are redrawn very slowly on browser.
These polygons are not fixed. I get information about which polygons need to be displayed from a web page and then from PostgreSQL view. Therefore I have passed viewParams in WMS service of GeoServer.
I use GeoWebCache.

But the problem I described above does not solve from GeoWebCache. Is there anything that I can try to improve performance?

Answer (score 2):

Set GeoServer logging to "GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER", check the query actually done in the logs, and run an "explain" of that query in PostgreSQL to see where the performance issues are.
References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/using-explain.html
- http://geoserver-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/webadmin/server/globalsettings.html

Once you have figured out what's slow, change your view definition accordingly (GeoServer adds bits around your query, but you have no control over them).